# Activity side-by-side lifecycle

Tags: android, android-activity, lifecycle

Imagine that I have an Activity A and I'm starting a new activity B from that one.

What will be the **Activities lifecycle side-by-side?**

```
 1. A: onCreate 
 2. A: onStart 
 3. A: onResume
```

on A => startActivity(B)

```
 4. B: onCreate
 5. B: onStart

 6. A: onPause

 7. B: onResume

 8. A: onStop
```

Is this correct?

Comment: Testing this with `Log.d()` and `logcat` will take less time than waiting for an answer to this question...

Comment: I was looking for a Android Developer site reference to confirm it, as the answer provided. My bad for not saying so...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Almost correct, just a minor difference. first A.onPause() and then B.onCreate()... etc

```
A: onCreate
A: onStart
A: onResume
```

on A => startActivity(B)

```
A: onPause
B: onCreate
B: onStart
B: onResume
A: onStop
```

Check this link for complete details

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#CoordinatingActivities

Comment: That's what I thought, but didn't have the link to back it up. Bookmarking :D

Comment: Thank you :-) I must be blind.. didn't see it.. I was looking for more of a graphic side-by-side events as for the single activity.

Answer (score 4):

There  is a beautiful app in the developer's site which shows the activity lifecycle, pls have a look at it.You can download the app's source code [here](http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/ActivityLifecycle.zip). Thought it might help someone :).

Comment: I can attest to this. This application, which comes in source code form and cannot be imported but rather should be "created from existing source, is absolutely wonderful and a huge must for any Android programmer trying to master the art of handling the life-cycle of activities. +1 and thank you for bringing this to my attention as I just didn't know about it before.